# IpHlpApi.dll: deleting ARP entry with DeleteIpNetEntry by passing MIB_IPNETROW

Tags: c#, .net, dll, arp

According to information I founded I use MIB_IPNETROW structure while processing my ARP edit program:

```
const int MAXLEN_PHYSADDR = 8;
const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MIB_IPNETROW
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwIndex;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwPhysAddrLen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst =
    MAXLEN_PHYSADDR)]
    public byte[] bPhysAddr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwAddr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwType;
}
```

And it's OK when I getting ARP table across GetIpNetTable() function, but the problem is in GetIpNetTable() which throws **System.AccessViolationException**: *'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'*

Here is the code of method (ArpRow just contains some fields, like addresses, for example):

```
public static void DeleteArpNote(ArpRow toDel)
    {
        MIB_IPNETROW pArpEntry = new MIB_IPNETROW();
        pArpEntry.dwPhysAddrLen = 0;
        pArpEntry.dwIndex = toDel.index;
        pArpEntry.dwAddr = BitConverter.ToInt32(toDel.ipAddress.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
        pArpEntry.bPhysAddr = toDel.macAddress.GetAddressBytes();
        pArpEntry.dwType = toDel.type;

        DeleteIpNetEntry(pArpEntry);
    }
```